# How to get element inside a td using Row index and td index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `Row Index` and `TD index` in a table and I want to select `input` element inside the cell in `[Row Index,TD Index]` . How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('tr:eq(rowIndex) td:eq(tdIndex) input')
```

[:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector for more information.

Answer (score 9):

Tables have accessor properties intended for direct access to individual cells, i.e.:

```
table.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex]
```

hence:

```
table.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

or:

```
$('input', table.rows[rowIndex].cells[colIndex])
```

Comment: This is actually much more reliable.

Comment: That seems to be the cleanest way

Answer (score 2):

```
var rowIndex = X;
var cellIndex = Y;
$('#my-table tbody')
    .children(':nth-child('+(rowIndex+1)+')')
      .children(':nth-child('+(cellIndex+1)+')')
        .find('input').val('Hello');
```

of course you can put em all a single selector

```
$('#my-table tbody tr:nth-child('+(rowIndex+1)+') td:nth-child('+(cellIndex+1)+')')
        .find('input').val('Hello');
```